# Why is type compatibility not applicable to primitives as well when overriding methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

When we say that a Base class `Base` and its derived class `Derived` are `type compatible` we refer to the fact that a `Base` reference can refer to a `Derived` instance.
I.e. `Base b = new Derived();`
For the oposite a casting would be needed as the types are not type compatible.
Now is this concept not applicable to primitive types?
I mean this

```
short shortNumber = 10;  
int intNumber = shortNumber;
```

seems like the same thing to me (as also no casting is needed and both `short` and `int` *are integral types*).
So when overiding a method in the base class, why is it acceptable that the return type be either the same or at least type compatible with the base's class return type but this is not applicable to integral types for example as well?
E.g.  why is this not acceptable?

```
public class Person {    

    public int getId(){  
        return 1;  
    }           
}   


public class Employee extends Person {    

    public short getId(){  
        return 0;  
    }  

}
```

Comment: Primitives aren't polymorphic.

Comment: @duffymo:I am only refering to the return type

Comment: It's true regardless of where you refer to them.

Comment: @user384706 Why don't you change your name ? Just curios...

Comment: @SoboLAN:Just lazy I guess.Why? Does SoboLAN mean anything more than userXXXX?

Comment: No, but it's a little more specific, more personal. It's more recognizable than just an ID number. I just had to ask :D . Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

The direct answer, why your code example is not valid, is simple: The Java language feature of **covariant return types** explicitly does **not** apply to **primitives**. See [JLS 8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5) and [JLS 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

Autoboxing does not apply here. If you changed your return types to `Integer` and `Short`, they would still not be return-type-substitutable, because neither is a subclass of the other.

I can not answer the question "why does the JLS not allow covariant return types for primitives", i.e. why the language designers decided it should not be allowed.

Comment: Primitives don't extend each other so there's nothing to co-vary.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 1.5, your shorts and ints are all auto-boxeable to `Short` and `Integer`, and Short does not extend Integer (e.g. it has a different MAX_VALUE).

That's one reason this would be problematic, but I think the true reasons are one of those java language design decisions: if you are going to be changing the type, we want you to be aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

you can not override method on the basis of return types, it's not allowed and compiler will complain that it'll not be treated as overridden method.

Also function calls are not deterministic on the bases of return types. For example if you call

someObj.getId();

How the compiler will determine which method should be called? does not matter from the compiler point of view that you are not handling the returned value.

Comment: The compiler would be able to determine it based on the actual object reference by `someObj` variable at runtime

Comment: but what if the method with the same signature and different return types declared in same class? It'll create ambiguity and that is why it's not allowed anywhere (inheritance in your case). Event if the return types are completely different they will create ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

1. [JLS #8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3): Requirements in Overriding and Hiding

   > If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.
   >   *This rule allows for covariant return types - refining the return type of a method when overriding it.*
2. [JLS #8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5): Method Return Type - objects and primitves are not treated in the same way (emphasis mine):

   > method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2, if and only if the following conditions hold:
   >
   > - If R1 is void then R2 is void.
   > - **If R1 is a primitive type, then R2 is identical to R1.**
   > - If R1 is a reference type then:
   >
   >   - **R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2** by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), or
   >   - R1 = |R2|

As for your initial example, it is called a widening conversion (short -> int) and does not apply in the context of method overriding.

Comment: But when I do a conversion to a wider type not info is lost. There is somewhat a compatibility of these types